# Thinking Sphinx - making indices sortable is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I've set up some indices and everything seems to work nicely, until I wanted to try getting the results sorted. I have several models, but the the one in which I am defining my indices is "Doctor". I'm defining them like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  define_index do
    indexes :firstname,  :sortable => true
    indexes :lastname,   :sortable => true
    indexes :sex,        :sortable => true
    indexes practice(:name),    :as => :practice_name,    :sortable => true
    indexes practice(:address), :as => :practice_address, :sortable => true

    # Added after denormalization
    indexes county(:name),        :as => :county
    indexes municipality(:name),  :as => :municipality

    # Can only filter on integers, thus CRC32-ing
    has "CRC32(sex)", :as => :sex_filter, :type => :integer
  end
end
```

Searching seems to be working just fine. When trying to sort on any of the attributes, I get an error like the following

> index employee_core: sort-by attribute 'firstname' not found

For firstname, lastname and sex. I am able to partially "solve" this by adding

> has firstname, lastname, sex

to the `define_index` block, but I'm not sure how to do the same for the references to another model (Practice), or if it is even possible.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong in the first place to make the `:sortable => true` not work, or how I might define the references to Practice as attributes as well?

---

An example of the call I'm making to Thinking Sphinx which is failing in the manner mentioned above:

```
ThinkingSphinx.search "<some search string>", {:with=>{}, :order=>:firstname, :sort_mode=>:desc, :page=>1}
```

Comment: just for sure, did you run `rake ts:rebuild` after adding `:sortable => true`?

Comment: Yes, I added :sortable => true first time I added the indices, and I've run rs:rebuild many times since then.

Comment: I meant ts:rebuild, of course.

Comment: What's the search query you're running that returns the error?

Comment: Pat: Glad to see the developer getting involved. :-) I'm not quite sure how to see the actual query being performed. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Btw, updated the question slightly, as the example was contrived. Now it contains the actual (stripped down) code as well as an example on how I'm calling ThinkingSphinx.search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the issue here is that Sphinx fields are not sortable at all. Thinking Sphinx gets around this by adding the `:sortable` option - which adds an attribute with the same name plus a _sort suffix - so, `firstname_sort` in this example.

When you're searching on a single model (`Employee.search`), Thinking Sphinx is able to refer to that model and see which fields are sortable, and automatically switch firstname to firstname_sort for you. However, you're searching globally, and so there's no easy reference for TS. Thus, the workaround is to use the full attribute name instead:

```
ThinkingSphinx.search "foo", :order => :firstname_sort, :sort_mode => :desc
```

Also: if you're searching across all indexed models, make sure attributes used in filters and sorting exist in all index definitions.

Adding :sortable to fields from associations will work fine too, given the same caveats.

Comment: Ahh, relieved to see there was an easy explanation to this. I'll try it out later and vote/accept the answer if it this works. Thanks in advance, Pat!